# Passing a ball trough different bags - bayes theorem

Tags: probability

So let's say we have `3 bags` that all contain `5 white` and `4 black balls`. Now we take a ball from the first bag, pass it to the 2nd bag, take the ball out of there and pass it to the third bag, and finally a ball from the third to 1st bag again.

What's the probability that the number of whites increased in the first bag?

The answer is 0,244 but I'm not sure how to get it.

For the number of white balls to increase in the first bag as far as I understand we can only take a black ball from there, from the second bag we can take ether black or white and from the third bagonly white so we pass it into the first bag. How to write this down?

Comment: Write down the conditional probabilities for the cases.

Comment: A tree diagram works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right:

This is of course the probability that the ball picked from bag 1 was black, and the one from bag 3 at the end is white, for otherwise, you don't get any increase in white balls for bag 1.

So, consider the following events:

A) black ball from bag 1 to bag 2 + white ball from bag 2 to bag 3 after that

B) black ball from bag 1 to bag 2 + black ball from bag 2 to bag 3 after that

Calculate the probability of each of these paths, and then multiply A by $0.6$ (because bag 3 has 6 out of 10 white balls now) and $B$ by $0.5$ (because bag 3 has 5 out of 10 white balls now) and add them up.

No Bayes' theorem needed.

So:

$P(A) = \frac{4}{9}\cdot \frac{5}{10}$ (5 out of 10 in bag 2 are white)

$P(B) = \frac{4}{9}\cdot \frac{5}{10}$ (5 out of 10 in bag 2 are black)

And $P = P(A)*0.6+P(B)*0.5$

Comment: Alrighty I was doing something like this, but for some reason didn't get the exact number, thanks!:)

Comment: @CyprusN Did this get the right number? I didn't even calculate ..  Oh yes, it does, since it's 1.1*2/9 = 1.1*0.222 = 0.2444.. Cool! Glad I could help!

Comment: @Bram28: well, actually , you  *have applied* the Bayes Theorem!

Comment: @Bram28 I have another question lol. So let's say we have 3 rooms and we lost a key in one of them. Probability to find the key in 1st one is A, in the 2nd B, if we search them nicely the prob. to find in 1st is A1 in 2nd is B2 and in 3rd C2. So I had a question about whats the probability that the key is in the 3rd room, I did A2*(1-A)+(1-B)*B2 and get the answer, but the second question is whats the prob that the key is in the 3rd room if we search them. I tried doing (1-A2)*(1-A)+(1-B2)*(1-B)+C but the answer isn't correct, any ideas?]

Comment: Its another  question, so make another post.

Answer (score 0):

The only draw sequences that work are

$$\text{B,W,W}\;\;\text{or}\;\;\text{B,B,W}$$

The sequence $\text{B,W,W}$ occurs with probability

$$
\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
\left(\frac{3}{5}\right) = \frac{2}{15} 
$$

and the sequence $\text{B,B,W}$ occurs with probability

$$
\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{9}
$$

hence the desired probability is

$$\frac{2}{15} + \frac{1}{9} = \frac{11}{45}$$